# Clean way to get the NSIndexPath of an object in an NSTreeController or NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

After poring through the documentation, I can find no reasonably easy way to get the index path of an object in an `NSOutlineView` or the `NSTreeController` it's bound to. As a result, I've ended up writing really ugly code trying to assemble an index path myself whenever I need to do something that requires them (removing specific items from the tree, for instance).

Is there no better way to do this than `[[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:<blah>] indexPathByAddingIndex: <blah>]`?

Comment: The linked answer only applies to an `NSTreeController` what's the solution for an `NSOutlineView` or dataSource ?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily build a path like so:

```
NSUInteger indexes[4] = {2, 3, 1, 0};
NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes length:4];
```

To get the index path of a particular model object, have a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9050488/50122).

Comment: `[_treeController.arrangedObjects descendantNodeAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[someOutline selectedRow]]]` has to be  one of _the grossest_ constructs / _bungles of an API_ that I have ever witnessed.  Apple should be *ashamed* of themselves.

Comment: Correctamundo. `NSTreeController` in general is not Apple's finest hour.

Comment: Wait, it's even worse.. just to get the "value" of the highlighted node in a "Tree Controlled" situation requires.. `[[[_treeController.arrangedObjects descendantNodeAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[sender selectedRow]]] representedObject] representedObject]` Lol. That double `representedObject` _drives me bananas_! It's like they were on crack... "Hey let's call it `objectValue`", "NO, I say `representedObject`, whhaaa!" ... "How about `selectionIndexes`", "No `selectedIndexPath`", "No, `NSOutlineViewSelectedPathIndexesPathBindingOption`! That's got a great ring to it." Ha!