# NSTreeController - Retrieving selected node

Tags: cocoa, nstreecontroller

I added Book object in bookController (NSCreeController). Now i want to get stored Book object when i select the row.

```
- (IBAction)addClicked:(id)sender {
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    // NSTimeInterval is defined as double

    NSUInteger indexArr[] = {0,0};
    Book *obj = [[Book alloc] init];
    NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle                                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    obj.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New %@",dateString];
    obj.filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",arc4random()%100000];
    [self.booksController insertObject:obj atArrangedObjectIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:2]];
}
```

Comment: What did you try to get the selected Book object?

Answer (score 0):

I concede there perhaps could be a better solution--

I am unfamiliar with how `NSTreeController` works, but I looked a the class reference and noticed that it has a `content` property, similar to an `NSArrayController` (Which I am familiar with grabbing specific objects from).
I believe that if the `content` property is actually of type of some kind of tree data structure, my answer here probably won't work.  The class reference says this about `content`:

> The value of this property can be an array of objects, or a
>   single root object. The default value is nil. This property is
>   observable using key-value observing.

So this is what I historically have done with the expected results:

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"(filename == %@) AND (title == %@)"), @"FILENAME_ARGUMENT_HERE", @"TITLE_ARGUMENT_HERE"];
NSArray *matchingObjects = [[self content] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString]];
```

Then simply calling `-objectAtIndex:` will grab you your object.  Note that the `NSArray` will be empty if the object doesn't exist, and if you have duplicate objects, there will be multiple objects in the array.

I also searched for an answer to your question, and found this SO thread:
[Given model object, how to find index path in NSTreeController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050028/given-model-object-how-to-find-index-path-in-nstreecontroller/9050488#9050488)

It looks pretty promising if my solution doesn't work, the author just steps through the tree and does an `isEqual` comparison.

If you could (if it's not too much trouble), leave a comment here to let me know what works for you, I'm actually curious :)

Comment: i could solve with selectedNodes method which returns an array of NSTreeNode in outlineDidSelect method.

Comment: So you got an array from selectedNodes, and applied a `NSPredicate` to it?

Comment: No i tried to get it NSArray of it, and then created NSTreeNode object.

Comment: Main thing is to change the method, you should use OutlineDidSelect method

Comment: ohhh okay I see what you're saying.  Cool :)

Comment: The content of NSTreeController isn't a list, it's a tree. filteredArrayUsingPredicate won't work.

Comment: Ye I prefaced my answer with that in the first paragraph :\  Was just throwing it out there in case it could help